# read very large dataset of xml files on spark

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

i want to read more than 180.000 xmls on spark and start a parsing process on each one so that in the end i get csv files as tables.
These xmls are compressed in a bz2 file. 
knowing that i have a 2 versions of this bz2:
one containing concatenated xmls(30mb each) and one single xmls.
The problem is that i get an executor lost error when reading single xmls version with

`sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat", "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable", "org.apache.hadoop.io.Text", conf={"textinputformat.record.delimiter": '\n\n'}).map(lambda num_line: num_line[1])`

and a `java.io.IOException: Too many bytes before newline` when rethem with

```
sc.textFile(hdfs_input_path).persist(pyspark.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

when using the following code to read the concatenated xml version

```
sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat", "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable", "org.apache.hadoop.io.Text", conf={"textinputformat.record.delimiter": '</delimiter>'}).map(lambda num_line: num_line[1])
```

it works sometimes only when the number of xml files is not too big as 180.000 approximatively.

So my question is how can i achieve the above cited task with bz2 compressed file format? is there another format tha could work?(Gzip is not splittable...)
let us forget about compression with bz2, is there another way to do this?

Iam using a CDH 5.7.0 with 283.20 GB physical memory and 42 VCores and 6 active nodes

Comment: Have you 180.000 xml files ? and each file is 30MB ? you can try to load batch by batch and process each batch then you can combine

Comment: @NarendraParmar the input is raw xml files, as output i have 11 .csv files that correspond to 11 table in hive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem. As I have `xml` files compressed in a `bz2` file, I have changed the delimiter to so that spark separates the `xmls` after it in `conf={"textinputformat.record.delimiter": '<\delimiter>'}` and then I added some `.map()` or `.filter()` operations to clean the separated `xmls`, i.e. deleting some unused tags etc.

But I didn't found out why I get such a error, as debugging in pyspark in general is not an easy task.